# $().datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added the datepicker function but I am not able to use it. I believe that it is I am doing some fundamental mistake since I am a beginner in javascript and jQuery.

The **input tag** is in the invite.html file which I am including using django's template tags all the jquery and semantic files I have downloded them in the static folder. I have added the datepicker.js files also I.Thanks in advance. I added and alert in the datepicker script it worked fine, So I think it is the function is added properly but

I get these errors:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Scholarship.html is the main html file in which I have included the invite.html file and the input tag id="datepicker" is in bold in invite.html the fuction that is generating the is in bold.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fusion!
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </title>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'globals/semantic-ui/components/reset.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'globals/semantic-ui/components/icon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'globals/css/semantic.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'globals/css/mediaquery.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'globals/css/semantic-notify.css' %}">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/jquery.min.js' %}"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/jquery.formset.js' %}"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/semantic-notify.js' %}"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/ajax-post.js' %}"></script>
    {% block css %}
    {% endblock %}

</head>

{% comment %}style="background-color: rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.1);"{% endcomment %}
<body id="body">

{% block body %}
    {% block navBar %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

    <div id="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="message" tag="{% if 'success' in message.tags %}green{% elif 'error' in message.tags %}red{% else %} blue {% endif %}" message="{{ message|safe }}"></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/semantic.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/dropdown.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/tab.js' %}"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#messages').find('.message').each(function(){
            $.uiAlert({
                textHead: $(this).attr('message'), // header
                text: '',
                bgcolor: $(this).attr('tag'), // background-color
                textcolor: '#fff', // color
                position: 'bottom-left',// position . top And bottom ||  left / center / right
                time: 3, // time
            });
        });

        $('#new-notification')
            .popup({
                inline: true,
                hoverable: true,
                position: 'bottom left',
                popup: $('#notificationPopup'),
                on: 'click',
                delay: {
                    show: 250,
                    hide: 500
                }
            })
        ;
    });
</script>
```

Scholarship.html

```
    {% extends 'globals/base.html' %}
        {% load static %}


        {% block title %}
            Awards & Scholarship
        {% endblock %}


        {% block body %}
            {% block navBar %}
                {% include 'dashboard/navbar.html' %}
            {% endblock %}

                        {% block winners %}
                            {% include 'scholarshipsModule/winners.html' with winners=winners %}
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                    {% comment %}The Personal Details end here!{% endcomment %}


                    {% comment %}The Publications starts here!{% endcomment %}
                    <div class="ui tab segment" data-tab="second">
                        {% block invite %}
                            {% include 'scholarshipsModule/invite.html' with release=release ch=ch time=time awards=awards form=form %}
                        {% endblock %} *invite.html is included here*
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                {% comment %}The right-rail segment ends here!{% endcomment %}

                {% comment %}The right-margin segment!{% endcomment %}
                <div class="column"></div>

            </div>


        {% endblock %}



        {% block javascript %}
            <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/datepicker.js' %}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/tablesort.js' %}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/editProfile.js' %}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/modal.js' %}"></script>
            <script>
                    $('.message .close')
              .on('click', function() {
                $(this)
                  .closest('.message')
                  .transition('fade')
                ;
              })
            ;
                **$( function() {
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); This is the code that generates the error
                } );**
                </script>
        {% endblock javascript %}


invite.html
        {% load static %}
        {% block winners %}


                        <div class="two fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label>Start date</label>

                                    <div class="ui input large left icon">
                                        <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                                        **<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="From" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required>
                                    </div>**

                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <label>End Date</label>

                                    <div class="ui input large left icon">
                                        <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                                        <input type="text" name="To" placeholder="YYYY-MMM-DD" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                    <div class="ui divider"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

This is the datepicker.js fuction which is their in the globals/js folder 

datepicker.js script
        $('.rangestart').calendar({
            type: 'date',
        });
        $('.rangeend').calendar({
            type: 'date',
        });

        $(".date.calendar").calendar({ type: "date" });
```

Comment: Where/when is jQuery included? It has to be included _before_ the `datepicker.js` (and the Semantic-UI)

Comment: @Andreas I thought the same, but if jQuery was missing then the error would be `$ is undefined`. Unless `$` is assigned to another framework... Either way there's not really enough info here to help.

Comment: The most likely cause of this problem is that `{% static 'globals/js/datepicker.js' %}` ends up 404ing. Check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. The next most likely cause is that you are loading jQuery twice and overwriting the version with datepicker attached to it. There isn't enough information in the question to tell what the real problem is with any degree of certainty though.

Comment: your datepicker.js is not loaded, May be this {% static 'globals/js/datepicker.js' %} is causing  issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Because of _"jQuery.Deferred exception: ..."_ there has to be an include for jQuery or it has to be part of one of the includes. Hence my guess on the wrong order.

Comment: Well guys is the order of imports in base.html could be causing the trouble

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> You should add this below script into your site.. after that your error will be remove.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#date1').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
});
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></script>
Date Picker: <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> <br/>
```